# Is it possible to call method within method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, sidekiq

Is it possible to reach method within method? For example:

```
class HardWorker < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def perform
    self.main_method
  end

  def main_method
    puts "main method"

    def simple_method  # how to call this from outisde?
      puts "simple method"
    end

    def another_method
      puts "another_method"
      # do stuff
    end
    another_method     #start running "another method in background"
  end
end
```

And i need to reach the "simple_method" inside "main method".

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do  # now it works like that:
  subscribe :event_name, :to => HardWorker, :with_method => :main_method
end
```

After triggering `:event_name`, on my console says `"main method"`. But i need to write there `"simple method"`, without restarting the `main_method`. I need to reach this `simple_method` inside `main_method`. Becouse `main_method` is already running in background, i need to reach inside of it a method and do many calculations. Im using sidekiq, so i cant use global variables outside the `main_method` scope. I think i need it to work something like:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do  # i wish it works, but it doesn't
  subscribe :event_name, :to => HardWorker, :with_method => :main_method[:simple_method]
end
```

Updated: I need to update this @global_object. If i recall "main_method", i will loose locally incremented @global_object. I need it to increment locally, but i cant recall main_method.

```
  def main_method

    @global_object = 0

    def simple_method
      @global_object += 100
    end

    def another_method
      (1..(2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1)).each do |number|
        # every second updating my data and sending to Redis DB
        @global_object++
        sleep 1
      end
    end
    another_method
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you are asking, but if you want to define class methods, why don't you just define class methods?

```
class HardWorker < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def perform
    self.main_method
  end

  def self.main_method
    puts "main method"
    self.simple_method
    self.another_method     #start running "another method in background"
  end

  def self.simple_method  # how to call this from outisde?
    puts "simple method"
  end

  def self.another_method
    puts "another_method"
    # do stuff
  end
end
```